# Mocking "fs" with Bun's test/mock

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, bun

I'm trying to mock `fs` using Bun's Jest compatible inbuilt test/mocking framework as described here:

https://bun.sh/docs/test/mocks

Following the example gives me code that looks like this:

```
import { expect, test, mock } from "bun:test";
import fs from "fs";

mock.module("fs", () => {
    console.log("Mocking")
    return {
        mkdirSync: (path: string) => { 
            console.log("mkdirSync", path);
            return "mocked";
        }
    };
});
console.log("Mocked fs")

test("Mkdir", async () => {
    const dir = fs.mkdirSync("mock-dir", { recursive: true });
    expect(dir).toBe("mocked");
});
```

The real function is still getting called though, not the mock, i.e. the test fails. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

This just happened to me...

You need to move the `mock.module("fs"...` into a separate file and use `--preload`

See this link: https://bun.sh/docs/test/mocks#hoisting-preloading